# Find Uppercase word between two characters

Tags: regex

Trying to find words between . and =, which are uppercase (optional and contain underscore between them) like UPPER_CASE

```
String myString = "test.UPPER_CASE=#123456"; //Should pass

if(myString.matches(".*\\.[A-Z]=")) {
    System.out.println("Match");
} else {
    System.out.println("No Match");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close, you just forgot to match the underscore and add the quantifier:

```
\.[A-Z_]+=
```

To use it from Java you can do this:

```
myString.matches(".*?\\.[A-Z_]+=.*")
```

That's the same pattern with `.*?` at the beginning and `.*` at the end, because the `matches` function requires the pattern to match the whole input string. I guess there's a better API available to get a substring match, but I don't use Java myself.

Comment: @Cozmonaut I guess it's because the `matches` method needs to match the whole pattern... Try this: `myString.matches(".*?\\.[A-Z_]+=.*")`

Comment: Thank you, This works great, can you update your original answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
.*\\.[A-Z_]+=
```

This should do it for you.